# Tree model does't go well on trend

Tags: time-series, forecasting, python, trend, boosting

I am using sales time series data 2011 onwards, to make predictions for upto 2 years. Other than date and holiday related features, i created moving averages, y/y ratios and lags. I also extracted seasonality using statsmodels.api.seasonal in Python and extrapolated it  as an additional feature. Here is my original series in orange, predictions in blue/gray.

[image]

All of this is fed into a XGB Model, that makes predictions in a self referential manner. My error for the year ahead is of the order of 10% and month ahead is about 2-3%, however, my model doesn't seem to capture trend at all. (I heard tree models suck at it?)

I tried a couple of ways to fix it.

1. Differencing the orginal series and then predicting resulted in a crazy series. I am not sure if tuning parameters for the model will fetch better results.

[image]

2. I tried to fit a curve of order 1,2 and log on the actuals and extrapolate it, then place the prediction on the same slope. This worked to some extent, but the result is not the best.

[image]

3. I extrapolated a Fourier of the actuals and did the same as 2, this also did not turn out to be the best result.

Any advice on how i can fix the model?